# Avoid Multiple ReRenders React Component after Randomizing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On page load I want React to render a component randomly because I have two different survey forms that I want randomly assigned to a user.  However, because of the multiple re-renders that react goes through the piece of code doesn't quite work the way I expected.

Sometimes, depending on the randomness, `<OpenSurvey />` will render first, then you'll see it briefly and it will switch to `<ClosedSurvey />`.

How do I handle this so that my RandomlyAssignSurvey function only renders once? Do I even need the useEffect hook there?

````
const SurveyPage = (props) => {

    useEffect( () => {
        RandomlyAssignSurvey()
    },[])

    const RandomlyAssignSurvey = () => {
        let openSurvey = "OpenSurvey"
        let closedSurvey = "ClosedSurvey"
        const pages = [openSurvey, closedSurvey]
        let page = pages[Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length)];

        console.log(page)
        if (page === "OpenSurvey") {
            return (
                <OpenSurvey/>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <ClosedSurvey/>
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <SceneContainer
            render={() =>   (
                <SurveyContainer>
                    {RandomlyAssignSurvey()}
                </SurveyContainer>
            )}
        />
    );
};```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your `render` prop is doing, but an easier approach to simply rendering a random component might look like this.

```
const SurveyPage = () => {
    return (
        Date.now()%2 === 1 ? <OpenSurvey/> : <ClosedSurvey/>
    );
};
```